# how can insert data into mongodb from android app?

Tags: android, mongodb

I want to insert my json data into mongo database, i import mongo Driver v 3.2.2 and create a database , collection in mlab.com but i cant send data in database such an document.

this is my code :

```
try {
    MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user:pass@ds041939.mlab.com:41939/vado");
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
    DB db = client.getDB(uri.getDatabase());
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("salam");

    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse("{'name':'mkyong', 'age':30}");


    collection.insert(dbObject);

    DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find();
    while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Any exception? Please [edit] to provide it

Comment: no error in Android studio But the document is not created.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Mongo, but I'd like to think there's a findAll method or the find method should accept some parameters. Otherwise, it's not clear why a object would not be inserted if no errors are generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was a little bit deprecated. I have adjusted it (used mongo-driver 3.2.2) and tested against my local mongo and it works fine:

```
try {
    MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);

    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
    MongoCollection<BasicDBObject> collection = db.getCollection("salam", BasicDBObject.class);

    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("name", "mkyong");
    document.put("age", 30);
    collection.insertOne(document);

    MongoCursor iterator = collection.find().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ensure that you install mongo driver via `maven` or `gradle` so you have all transient dependencies as well because mongo driver requires `bson` and `mongodb-driver-core`.